# adding to numerical value of column

Tags: php, mysql

Hi so I was wondering what the best way to add or subtract from a field in my table would be. The way I know it would work is if I query the value do the addition and then UPDATE the value.

I would rather include the addition as part of the update query like:

```
UPDATE users SET points = +10
```

Or something like that. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to name the column on the right hand side of the `=` operator:

```
UPDATE `users` SET `points` = `points`+10
```

Since there is no `WHERE` clause this will give all users 10 more points then they currently have.

Answer (score 2):

You can just do this:

```
UPDATE users SET points = points + 10
```